# Let $a,b>0$ be real numbers satisfying $a^2+b^2=2$. Prove that $a+b \leq 2$.

Tags: inequality

I've tried messing around with some AM-GM stuff but I can't think of anything else for this. Can I get a proof for Real numbers? (I had a proof for rationals but can't work for reals).

Comment: Hint:

$$2(a^2+b^2)=(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2\ge(a+b)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a^2+b^2\le 2$, then
by AM-RMS inequality $$\frac{a+b}{2} \le \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}} = 1 \implies (a+b) \le 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use C-S,
$$
2(a^2 + b^2) \geqslant (a + b)^2\Rightarrow4\geqslant (a + b)^2 \Rightarrow2\geqslant a + b
$$
This is true for all real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Just another graphic approach.

If you plot $x^2+y^2=2$ you'll get the circumference of center the origin and radius $\sqrt2$.

If you calculate the tangent of this curve at $(1,1)$, you'll get $x+y=2$.

So the whole circle $x^2+y^2=2$ lies on the semiplane $x+y\le2$ (in fact, the circle on "touch" the line). So $x^2+y^2=2$ implies $x+y\le 2$.

MOREOVER.

With the same technique, plotting the tamnget line to the circle at $(-1,-1)$, you'll get $x+y=-2$. So $x^2+y^2=2$ implies $|x+y|\le 2$ and the equality olds if and only if $x=y$.

ANALITICALLY:

$x^2+y^2=2$ $\iff$ $2x^2+2y^2\pm 2xy =4$ $\iff$ $(x^2+y^2+2xy)+(x^2+y^2-2xy)=4$ $\iff$ $(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2=4$.

But $(x+y)^2\le (x+y)^2+(x-y)^2=4$, so $(x+y)^2\le 4$ whence $-2\le x+y\le 2$ and you're (another time), done.

Answer (score 0):

Polar coordinates.

Let $a=r\sin t;$ $y=r \cos t,$ where $r=√2.$

Maximize $a+b= r(\sin t +\cos t);$

$√2(\sin t +\cos t)=$

$√2(√2(\sin (π/4+t)) \le 2 \cdot 1.$